# Remove everything in parentheses java using regex

Tags: java, regex

I've used the following regex to try to remove parentheses and everything within them in a string called `name`.

```
name.replaceAll("\\(.*\\)", "");
```

For some reason, this is leaving name unchanged.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Strings are immutable. You have to do this:

```
name = name.replaceAll("\\(.*\\)", "");
```

Edit: Also, since the `.*` is greedy, it will kill as much as it can. So `"(abc)something(def)"` will be turned into `""`.

Comment: Actually, as I think about it a bit more, nesting won't be an issue because the `.*` is greedy by default. The real issue is with strings like `(abc) (def)` which will be deleted completely.

Comment: Also not a problem in my situation. There will never be more than one set of parentheses.

Answer (score 11):

As mentionend by by Jelvis, ".*" selects everything and converts "(ab) ok (cd)" to ""

The version below works in these cases "(ab) ok (cd)" -> "ok", by selecting everything except the closing parenthesis and removing the whitespaces.

```
test = test.replaceAll("\\s*\\([^\\)]*\\)\\s*", " ");
```

Comment: This fails when `test="(text(some more text ) then some more )"`.

Answer (score 4):

[`String.replaceAll()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) doesn't edit the original string, but returns the new one. So you need to do:

```
name = name.replaceAll("\\(.*\\)", "");
```

Answer (score 2):

If you read the [Javadoc for `String.replaceAll()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), you'll notice that it specifies that the resulting string is the *return value*.

More generally, `String`s are immutable in Java; they never change value.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using this function:

```
public static String remove_parenthesis(String input_string, String parenthesis_symbol){
    // removing parenthesis and everything inside them, works for (),[] and {}
    if(parenthesis_symbol.contains("[]")){
        return input_string.replaceAll("\\s*\\[[^\\]]*\\]\\s*", " ");
    }else if(parenthesis_symbol.contains("{}")){
        return input_string.replaceAll("\\s*\\{[^\\}]*\\}\\s*", " ");
    }else{
        return input_string.replaceAll("\\s*\\([^\\)]*\\)\\s*", " ");
    }
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
remove_parenthesis(g, "[]");
remove_parenthesis(g, "{}");
remove_parenthesis(g, "()");
```

Answer (score 1):

To get around the `.*` removing everything in between two sets of parentheses you can try  :

```
name = name.replaceAll("\\(?.*?\\)", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin we must use toRegex.

```
val newName = name.replace("\\(?.*?\\)".toRegex(), "");
```