# Regex to remove spaces within square brackets (Java)

Tags: java, regex

I need a regex to remove spaces within square brackets. For example:

- add eax [ebp + 8]
- add eax [esp + 12]

will become

- add eax [ebp+8]
- add eax [esp+12]

Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206128/remove-everything-in-parentheses-java-using-regex

Comment: better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29610585/remove-specific-characters-inside-parentheses-using-regex

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
String str = "add eax [ebp + 8]";
str.replaceAll(" (?=[^\\[]*])", "");
```

Ouput: `add eax [ebp+8]`

Comment: regex part looks OK, but it is Java question so (1) `var str` is incorrect, (2) strings are immutable so `replaceAll` can't affect string in `str` variable, it creates new string based on original string, so you will need to store this result somewhere (maybe even in `str` with `str = str.replaceAll(...)`).

Comment: Thanks so much James.

Comment: @Pshemo True, I've been doing too much C# lately. By output I meant the output of the function call.