# Regex to remove parentheses

Tags: java, regex

I have a `TreeMap` in Java where some of the keys are of the type `ABC (1)`, `ABC (2)` with only numbers inside the parentheses.

I would like to remove the `(1)` and `(2)` along with the preceding blank space and end up with only `ABC`.

I am really bad at regex, I know it must be a very simple regex for some of the members here, but I would like to find the regex to replace the `" (1)"` and `" (2)"` with `""`.

Thanks a lot for any help in advance.

Comment: Similar, but not quite a duplicate of the linked post, in which the contents within the parentheses are anything, and the discussion revolves around whether `String.replaceAll()` modifies the string on which it is invoked.

Comment: My comment above referred to the no longer mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206128/remove-everything-in-parentheses-java-using-regex question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
key.replaceAll(" \\([\\d]+\\)", "")
```

The line above should return the key with such space-prefixed parenthesized numbers removed. Escaping of the parentheses makes them a literal match, rather than a submatch grouping/capture operator.

I used [RegexPlanet's regex tester for java](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html) to test the regex, and the [String#ReplaceAll documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) to verify Java replacement of a regex match usage.

Comment: While the duplicate I linked to could be used to figure out the answer, in my opinion, you're answer better explains and links to helpful outside resources. +1

Comment: Your link was helpful. Thanks for the compliment on my answer.

Comment: That worked. Thanks a lot @MarkA.Fitzgerald
Even though it is highly improbably to have a letter/word instead of a number inside the parenthesis, I would still like to search for it. Just for Fail-safe.
Can you please help me with the regex to look for a word OR a number inside the parenthesis
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: You're welcome. Could you update your question with this change of requirement so that I can update my answer accordingly? The answer change, in brief, is probably to change `\\d` to `\\w`. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html under "Summary of regular-expression constructs" under "Predefined character classes" for details on `\\w`.